# Vertically Center SGV View Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, viewbox

I'm trying to vertically align a SGV View Box within a DIV through CSS but I keep failing. I'm only capable of horizontally centering it by the `width='100%'` attribute. Applying some CSS tricks to vertically align it has failed as well. I really have no idea how to tackle this.

Code example:

```
<div class="sgvContainer" id="sgvTest" style="opacity: 0;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" viewBox="0 0 358.98 700.6" width="100%">
        <path d="M0,122.7h300 " />
    </svg>
</div>
```

The dimensions I have for `viewBox=""` are not perfect. I would love to find alternatives where I can avoid this method so it stretches the SGV automatically.

When it stretches, the SGV should be in a "center" (fit-to-screen) display where it stretches to max-width of the browser and vertically centers in the middle of the page.

```
-----------------
|               | // Potentially empty space at the top
|    ========   |
|===============| // = would be any SGV
|    ========   |
|               | // Potentially empty space at the bottom
-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some wrapper to do that vertical-align. Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/KAngel7/rb2rx8tq/).

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.